# How to display a matrix in a chart in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

How to display a matrix in a chart? I can do this in Python using:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_filter(filters,tex):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for i in range(filters.shape[0]):
        for j in range(filters.shape[1]):
            c = hori[i][j]
            ax.text(i+0.5, j+0.5, str(c), va='center', ha='center')

    ax.set_xlim(min_val, filters.shape[0])
    ax.set_ylim(min_val, filters.shape[1])
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(filters.shape[0]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(filters.shape[1]))
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.grid()

    plt.title(tex)

hori = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
plot_filter(hori, 'Horizontal')
```

How to do this in MATLAB?

The result should look like this:

[image: result_matrix]

Comment: Since matplotlib is based on MATLAB graphics syntax, it should be relatively straightforward to translate the Python code to MATLAB. Interestingly, you've gotten a completely different answer than I expected. Nonetheless, for future questions, it is always better to first make an attempt yourself, you'll learn more and you'll produce, in general, questions that are more useful to a larger audience.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry I don't know much about MATLAB. I've tried to convert this to matlab code, but it seems that subplot cannot be called like matplotlib, so I got real subplots with different axis. The result looks very different, and I cannot find anything about this issue online, so I guest we should do it differently in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cellplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellplot.html) for this purpose.

```
h = cellplot({0 1 0; 0 2 0; 0 1 0});
title('Horizontal');
```

which gives:

[image: img1]

and to remove the red boxes, use:

```
set(h(2:2:end),'EdgeColor', [1 1 1], 'FaceColor', [1 1 1]);
```

[image: img2]

Comment: This is a nice approach, I'll just add that if your data is stored in a matrix `A = [0 1 0; 0 2 0; 0 1 0];` you can convert to a cell array of the proper form with `C = mat2cell(A,[1 1 1],[1 1 1]);`

Comment: I did not know about this function. Thank you yet again for teaching me something!